# All is well. So does all dogs bark? Or Do all dogs bark?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

All is well.  This is the accepted form in English grammar.
Which one of the following form is correct by this convention:

1. Does all dogs bark?
2. Do all dogs bark?

Comment: In the phrase 'All is well' _all_ means _everything_.

Comment: On the dogs, Do all dogs bark? is right. How could it not be so?

Answer (score 1):

> **All is well.** This is the accepted form in English grammar. Which one of the following form is correct by this convention:
> In this context, **all** is a singular noun = Everything.

In *Do all dogs bark*, **all** is an adjective/determiner (modifying "dogs") The subject of the sentence is "dog**s**" - dogs is plural - therefore its verb is in the plural form = "do".

As a pronoun, **all** can be plural if it refers set of people or things:

A: "Where are the children?"

B: "All are in bed." = {All of them} are in bed.

Answer (score 0):

The intent matters when considering whether “all” should have singular or plural agreement.

“All” is used as a collated whole in “all is well”, hence the use of singular agreement. It isn’t each piece in a collection of individual pieces that is said to be “well” - the (single) whole is said to be well.

However, if you were asked a question about the well-being of a group of people, “all” references the group of individuals as a plurality. “All are well” would mean that each individual within the group is well, as opposed to “the situation is well” if you said “all *is* well”.

When you talk about “all dogs”, however, you are referencing a collection of individual dogs. That plurality of dogs requires plural agreement, hence “all dogs bark”.

Comment: The pronoun usage should be contrasted with the determiner usage overtly (on ELU).